# c file i/o- how to write file and save even if the program is quitted?

Tags: c, file, io

I am learning C file i/o and have a question about how to save changes in file after I quit the program.

I have a 'heights.dat' file that stores 5 heights in binary number format.

Then, my program reads the 'heights.dat' file and executes the command by options

1-> display the elements of height in the array

2-> multiply 2 for every element in the array

3-> quit the program.

The problem is, when I quit the program, it does not save the multiplied value to the array.

For instance, the initial values in the array were 100 200 300 400 500. When I choose option 2, quit the program, and relaunch the program, the values in the array should be 200 400 600 800 1000. However, the values in the array are unchanged.

I was thinking of creating another write mode file, but it doesn't work, too. Is there binary mode that supports both read and write?

```c
#include<stdio.h>

void menu();

int main(void) {        
    int choice = 0;
    int numberlist[5];
    FILE *readptr;
    readptr = fopen("heights.dat", "rb");
    //FILE *writeptr;
    //  writeptr = fopen("heights.dat", "wb");

    do {
        menu(); 
        scanf("%d", &choice);

        if (choice == 1) {
            fread(&numberlist, sizeof(int), 5, readptr);
            for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
                printf("%d ", numberlist[i]);
            }
            printf("\n");
        }
        else if (choice == 2) {
            for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
                numberlist[i] = 2 * numberlist[i];
            }
            fwrite(&numberlist, sizeof(int), 5, readptr);
        }
        else if (choice == 3) {
            break;
        }
        else {
            printf("you entered wrong choice number\n");
        }
    }
    while (choice != 3);

    printf("exit the program\n");
    fclose(readptr);
    //  fclose(writeptr);
    return 0;
}

void menu() {
    printf("1 display all the numbers in \"height.bat\" \n");
    printf("2 multiply all the numbers by 2\n");    
    printf("3 quit\n"); 
    printf("your choice is: ");
}
```

Comment: You need to use the file open option "r+b", to be able to also write in the same file.

Comment: Maybe you can use `atexit()` and a callback to write the file.  Be cautious about that, though.

Comment: So you're saying the `frwite` is failing, Maybe you should check what error it returned...

Comment: @Jonathan Leffler, That won't help. The question is misphrased. They're using `fwrite`, but not seeing the intended effect of `fwrite`. It would be easier to have noticed this if the code was properly indented...

Comment: @ikegami — there was a good reason for including 'maybe' in my comment, then, though I wasn't aware of why at the time I included it.

Comment: `fwrite(..., readptr)` shows that you named the variable well, but didn't pay attention to the naming.  You can't write to a file opened for reading.  You commented out the code in which you opened the file for writing, probably because it was truncating the file.

Comment: Good catch, @William Pursell. And the solution is to open and close the handles inside the `1` and `2` case-handling blocks.

Comment: In general, it's a really bad idea to modify files.  If you want to modify a file, instead write to a different file and relink when you're done.  (eg, rename the new file to the old one.)  Far less chance of data corruption that way.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler I have never used atexit() function, but I will google it later.

Comment: @ikegami Thank you for the advice! But what does mean ' open and close the handle'?

Comment: Using `fopen` and `fclose`